# How to output difference of files from two folders and save the output with the same name on different folder

Tags: linux, shell, diff

I have two folders which have same file names, but different contents. So, I am trying to generate a script to get the difference and to see what is being changed. I wrote a script below :

```
folder1="/opt/dir1"
folder2=`ls/opt/dir2`

find "$folder1/" /opt/dir2/ -printf '%P\n' | sort | uniq -d

for item in `ls $folder1`
do
 if [[ $item == $folder2 ]]; then
  diff -r $item $folder2 >> output.txt
 fi
done
```

I believe this script has to work, but it is not giving any output on output folder. 
So the desired output should be in one file . Ex:

```
cat output.txt

diff -r /opt/folder1/file1 /opt/folder2/file1
1387c1387
<               ALL X'25' BY SPACE                                                
---

>               ALL X'0A' BY SPACE      

diff -r /opt/folder1/file2 /opt/folder2/file2
2591c2591
<               ALL X'25' BY SPACE                                                
---
>               ALL X'0A' BY SPACE
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `diff -r /opt/dir1 /opt/dir2` ??

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I need to store the output in one file with each difference, if it is possible. I edited my question .

Comment: `the output in one file with each difference` - so why is `diff -r` not for you? Anything wrong with `diff -r /opt/dir1 /opt/dir2 > output.txt` ?

Comment: I have added -r option after you advised me on your first reply.

Comment: 1. Remove the whole script. 2. Start with empty script. 3. Write exactly `diff -r /opt/dir1 /opt/dir2 > output.txt` and have nohing else. I don't mean "put -r inside what you have". I mean to run exactly `diff -r /opt/dir1 /opt/dir2 > output.txt`.

Comment: If I run diff -r , it just giving me the file names which differ from each other, but I need to see also the content of difference of each file.

Comment: Then what is wrong with the common `diff -Naur`...

Comment: So the diff command shows the difference of two files but not the folders, if I execute diff /opt/folder1 /opt/folder2 , it is just giving me strings that file1 differs from file1, and that's it. It is not showing me the actual difference inside of the files

Comment: So do `diff -Naur /opt/dir1 /opt/dir2 > output.txt`. Diff is a really, really big and bigger command, you can do anything with it. Writing your own script to handle that is reinventing the wheel. You can format output format with diff. Read it's manual.

Comment: diff -Naur is good as well, but I was trying to generate the output more readable. Like I mentioned on my question , that the desired output supposed to show difference of which file and what is the exact difference.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So twofold:

1. First get the files in one folder. Never use `ls`. Forget it exists. `ls` is for nice printing in our console. In scripts, use `find`.
2. Then for each file do some command. A simple `while read` loop.

So:

```
{
    # make find print relative to `/opr/dir1` director
    cd /opt/dir1 &&
    # Use `%P` so that print without leading `./`
    find . -mindepth 1 -type f -print "%P\n"
} |
while IFS= read -r file; do
     diff /opt/dir1/"$file" /opt/dir2/"$file" >> output/"$file"
done
```

Notes:

- always quote your variable
- [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Thank you for the help. How about if I add find command to my existing script? 
I updated my question.